# How i solve this error?

Tags: 18.04, python, dependencies, opencv

My Code is

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('img.jpg',0)
cv.imshow('image',img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

And the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "opencv.py", line 5, in <module>
cv.imshow('image',img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /tmp/build/80754af9/opencv-suite_1535558553474    /work/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:632: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

Comment: Did you try what is mentioned in the message? What is your OS?

Comment: How exactly did you install opencv? are you using anaconda python?

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Install the two missing dependency packages. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config python3-opencv
```

The Python code in the question runs successfully in Ubuntu 18.04 after installing these packages. The packages that I have installed all came from the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories.

- python3 - version 3.6
- python3-numpy
- python3-opencv
- libgtk2.0-dev
- pkg-config

Comment: No does not work. Same problem shows

Comment: The Python code in the question runs without error in my Ubuntu 18.04. This indicates that you possibly have an underlying package management issue. I installed all the packages necessary to this code from the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories.

Comment: Yes I have some problems in my computer i think. Various library take problem to install and work.

Comment: So Should I install my os

Comment: I added a list of the necessary packages to install in Ubuntu 18.04 to my question, so it's not necessary to reinstall the OS. Just get rid of the non-repo garbage that you installed and replace it with packages from the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories.

Comment: All are installed already

Comment: Yes it is in this directory

Comment: You possibly did something weird with pip or Anaconda which resulted in the Python 3 interpreter not importing the right cv2 module which was installed by apt from the python3-opencv p[ackage.

Comment: How I solve this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103735/discussion-between-karel-and-ujjwal-kar).